# Direction of friction in complicated physics problems

Tags: forces, friction

I want to ask how to determine direction of friction in complicated mechanical problems (for example 5 masses each over other and 3 forces on these masses in 3 different directions and friction between every masses)?

Is there a absolute way to find direction of friction or I have to calculate it each time for each different case ?

Comment: Best way to find that is to imagine the relative motion between the blocks in absence of friction and then direct friction opposite to the blocks' sliding tendencies.

Answer (score 0):

If the block is moving, the direction of the frictional force is in the opposite of the relative motion of the block compared to the frictional surface.

If on the other hand it is a static situation the frictional force is in the direction opposite to the direction that the blocks would move if it were a friction-less system.